# How to save canvas image into sdcard of device in android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Show image in Canvas
draw on canvas

it is working fine...

How to save this image in device gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this javascript library: [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)

You can save the canvas data to image file (PNG, JPEG or BMP).

To save it into device gallery, you can use [this PhoneGap plugin](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/saving-image-to-android-devices-gallery-phonegap-android/)

Comment: I have edited my post with a link that have the code to save image into Android device gallery